# Progress Bar in Modal not updating

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have created a PHP upload class that takes a file as input and copies it to the server,  this side of the application works fine.  My issue that I am having is showing the progress bar updating within a bootstrap modal.  The modal shows and I can see the progress bar within the Modal I just don't see the progress bar updating.

I have done the JS code and I have tested that this works, by taking the progress bar HTML out from the modal and placing it on the upload form page and this works fine.

my theory was that maybe the modal is causing the JS to lose context?

```
$("form").submit(function() {
     //$("#loadingModal").modal("show");

     $form = $(this);

     uploadVideo($form);
});

function uploadVideo($form){
  var formdata = new FormData($form[0]); //formelement

  var ajax= new XMLHttpRequest();

  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){
    var percent = (event.loaded /event.total) * 100;

    $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent+'%');
    //console.log(percent);
  });

  //progress completed load event

  ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    $form.find('.progress-bar');
  });

  ajax.open("POST", "processing.php");
  ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested I have resolved this in the end I needed to expose the Modal properties so I added this:

```
var $el = $("#loadingModal");
```

I was then able to update the code as follows:

```
  ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){
    var percent = (event.loaded /event.total) * 100;

    $el.find('.progress-bar').width(percent+'%');
    //console.log(percent);
  });

  //progress completed load event

  ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event){
    $el.find('.progress-bar');

  });
```